# Is listunspent scalable and efficient?

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind, bitcoinj

Is the listunspent bitcoind api command efficient and scalable? 
Say I had 5000 daily transactions on my bitcoind and I pinged bitcoind with listunspent every minute to keep my db updated, for example.

Any good alternatives if so?

Comment: Should be asked on http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I call `listunspent` 86,400 times a day per client, and I have about 10 clients pointing to the same bitcoin daemon, so that makes it a total of say close to a million calls per day, and it works absolutely fine without a need to restart for weeks.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, I've asked everywhere, no one has real concrete answers/experience/examples to give me.

So lets say I had 10-15 coin daemons (i.e. bitcoin/dogecoin/litecoin etc). With thousands of little transactions coming in each day to each daemon. Do you think my CPU/RAM numbers would be crazy high if I was pinging all those daemons every minute with listunspent, to keep my DB up to date?

Comment: @user3296059 check out my answer to this post: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/24434/minimal-system-to-run-a-full-bitcoin-node-netbook-raspberry-pi-etc/24435 it will give you a clue on what is the minimal configuration you should have to run a full node, regarding your `listunspent` concerns they should initiate higher local disks I/O but that's all, it's not one of the resource-demanding commands.

Comment: Thanks George, I'm using SSD's, i7s, 32GB RAM. High disk I/O's are something I think my server can handle. Thanks again, and I'm reading through the post now, cheers!